# Where to store UI config in a java web app and read-write the config file from jsp page

Tags: java, javascript, user-interface, config

I need to save some ui preferences selected by the admin, thinks like list of columns names to display in a table and other such display data that can be configured from the ui itself. Once its configured it will be saved in a file and then the file will be read subsequently to determine the display details and also send that data to backend service for querying.

As its purely for ui purposes, I don't want to store it in the core module or in the backend DB, but would like to store it in the web module along side the html/jsp files. Has anyone done something like this - I was trying to figure out if there is a easy way to write files from jsp/html but it doesnt seem to be straightforward. If that is not recommended, any other suggestions on dealing with this scenario will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Seems open to opinion. Implement with maximum simplicity and consistency. And no one can say ye nae

Comment: That doesn't really answer my question. Can files be written/read from jsp/html pages?

Comment: Sorry - I know it's not a definitive response. It was a *comment* not an *answer*. Obviously I have no great practical advice :S

Comment: No worries, thanks. I was making sure that my questions were clear enough.

Comment: I haven't met your situation exactly... But maybe UI preferences are something you can store within the user's browser?  It seems something that is defined by the browsing environment; hence perfect for browser storage. cookies/localStorage/indexedDB? IDK

Comment: That won't work for my case, because I need the preferences to be accessible across machines. So, its needs to be saved on the server (in the ui module).

Comment: I fully respect your requirements, but UI preferences stored at a x-browser level sounds questionable. Do you cater for devices at all - they would require an entirely separate set of preferences IMHO

Answer (score 1):

Storing data like this in a file is usually no good practice. It won't work in distributed environments, the container's security manager may prohibit it, etc. If you know what you're doing, you *can* get at the container's configuration directory via a system property and write to that folder, but you definitely do not want to write into the WAR itself, even if it is exploded.

The natural place to store settings made from the UI is the database, no matter whether these settings are UI related themselves. This is portable, transactional, and easy to implement.

Comment: Thanks. I was going back and forth on storing in the DB. But kept thinking that storing it in the backend DB would mean that backend is aware of those settings even though it holds meaning only for the UI. If its per user settings, then I agree that DB is the best place but in my case its a system level setting so I wasn't sure. I might just store it in the DB for lack of better/simpler solution.

Comment: Maybe I am misreading your question. It seemed to me the settings are editable by the user and then sent to the backend anyway, so the question was just how to store them, and not whether the backend should be aware of them.

Comment: Yes, but my point was that it should be something that is passed to the backend in a request and not something that the backend can read by itself (which I know it doesnt have to but it can). Discussing this here did help me clear my mind though, I do plan to store it in the DB and have UI send it to the backend when making a request for the data. Thanks.